# Remove text from current cursor position to previous occurrence of space in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to remove text from current cursor position to previous occurrence of space in  EditText.

Example:

```
                I am good at writing | articles.
```

If the above is the text in the EditText and `|` is notated as cursor position then I want to remove text 'writing' from EditText.

Is there any best way to do so. I tried with following code

```
                 int in= editext.getSelectionStart();
                 String myText = editext.getText().toString();
                 String s = myText.substring(0, in);
                 //here I got problem, how to remove and set text to Exdittext
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
   int in = editText.getSelectionStart();
            String myText = editText.getText().toString();
            if (in >= 0) {
                String before = myText.substring(0, in);
                String after = myText.substring(in);
                if(before.length()>=1) {
                    String newBefore = before.substring(0, before.length() - 1);
                    String outputText = newBefore + after;
                    editText.setText(outputText);
                    editText.setSelection(in-1);
                }
            }
```

steps:

1. Getting the cursor index
2. Getting the whole text from editText then saving in myText
3. Getting the text before the cursor and saving in the before
4. Getting the text after the cursor and saving in the after
5. Getting the characters from index = 0 to index = (before    length
   minus 1)    Concatenate the newBefore and after.
6. Setting the    outputText in editText
7. Setting the cursor index

   Example: I am good at writing| articles.

   Output = I am good at writin| articles.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = editText.getText().toString(); 
int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();
String beforeCursor= s.substring(0, selectionStart);
String afterCursor= s.substring(selectionStart, s.length());
String[] words = beforeCursor.split(" ");
beforeCursor=  beforeCursor.replace(words[words.length-1],"");
editText.setText(beforeCursor+afterCursor);
```

steps:

> 1. Get the editText string.
> 2. Split the string into two/ before and after the cursor
> 3. Get all the words in beforeCursor string seperated by " "
> 4. remove the last such string from beforeCursor
> 5. append both before and afterCursor string and set it back to editText/ (if you want the cursor to be back to where it was, dont
>      forget to do setSelection(selectionStart)

Answer (score 0):

```
        private EditText outputResult;
        outputResult = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.display);


        String enteredInput = outputResult.getText().toString();
        int end = outputResult.getSelectionEnd();

    if(enteredInput.length() > 0){
      String beforeCursor= enteredInput.substring(0, end-1);
      String afterCursor= enteredInput.substring(end,enteredInput.length());
      enteredInput= beforeCursor+afterCursor;
      outputResult.setText(enteredInput);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.